# ArrayList emptied out after receiving data from FireStore after OnCompleteListener, how can I save it?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have data that should be visible in code that I get from FireStore collection and add it to ArrayList, I know that it happens because get() method returns immediately so the query isn't done yet, and hence the onCreate() method won't see any data, but is there a way to save that data in ArrayList and use it somewhere else?

For example here is two versions of code:
1st one make Toast with whole list like it should:

```
        db.collection("Users Data")
                .document(currentUserID)
                .collection("Follows")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                following.add(document.getId());
                                Toast.makeText(SearchedProfile.this, following.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

and 2nd make Toast with empty ArrayList (Toast says '[]')

```
        db.collection("Users Data")
                .document(currentUserID)
                .collection("Follows")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                following.add(document.getId());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

        Toast.makeText(SearchedProfile.this, following.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Only difference is a position of Toast method.

Comment: because your code isn't synchronous - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value. so make use of your data when you have it, or use callbacks

Comment: The `Toast` gets called before your `oncomplete` runs. As **a_local_nobody** pointed out you'd have to call your methods that use the data in a callback when `oncomplete` runs.

Comment: There is no way you can do that. Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicate to see how can you solve this using a callback. You might also be interested in reading this article, [How to read data from Cloud Firestore using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You received an empty array list because your code [isn't synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value).

In other words the Toast gets called before your oncomplete runs.
You need to call your methods that use the data in a callback when oncomplete runs.